# JPanel with FlowLayout resizes itself

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, miglayout, flowlayout

I have JPanel inside JFrame (but they are not the same sized and JFrame is full screen). JPanel has a FlowLayout, because I dynamically add there small squares (JPanels). That squares are being arranged well (they move to the next row as JPanel ends), until I resize JFrame - then those squares are shown in one row, what makes a part of them invisible (they disappear as the screen ends) and the JPanel resizes. What can I do to keep the permanent size of JPanel? The LayoutManager of JFrame is MigLayout.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution: override its getPreferredSize() method to return a constant Dimension.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PANEL_W = 400;
   private static final int PANEL_H = 300;

   public MyPanel() {
      // ... etc...
   }


   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PANEL_W, PANEL_H);
   }

   // ... etc...
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I can't define width and height from advance because I made JPanel growing, to take all possible place to fit the screen (so dimension depends on the size of screen). To be more specific, my JFrame is divided into two columns (according to MigLayout): first has permanent size and second takes all space left.

Comment: Besides, this code is not working. Even if I define the size of JPanel, it changes when I resize window or call validate() function on JFrame.